# Would this mIRC script be possible? how difficult?

Tags: scripting, mirc

At my workplace we use mIRC for realtime communication for those of us who need to be constantly in touch with others. Sometimes it happens that I have to leave my desk for an hour or two at a time, and sometimes I get a PM in mIRC that I need someone to get me for.

So, my question is, with the scripting capability of mIRC, is it possible to set up a script that, when running, if I receive a PM it will automatically send a PM to another user that I specify to let him know to give me a call or something? Would it be easy to implement?

(if it would be quick and easy and someone wants to write it for me, that'd be super and worth a top answer vote :P mainly just need to know if its possible and how difficult it would be though)

We use mIRC 6.16 if that matters. Its an older release.

Comment: that posts a message in the irc window thats only visible to the specified user, which is an excellent start. Can it be changed to do a PM to the user instead of his chat window? Just to make it more noticable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Yes it's easy.

It's like one line of code. This might work, haven't tried it though since I haven't used mIRC in years, probably made a mistake somewhere..

```
on *:TEXT:*:?:/notice NICKNAME Got PM, Call me!
```

Comment: that posts a message in the irc window thats only visible to the specified user, which is an excellent start. Can it be changed to do a PM to the user instead of his chat window? Just to make it more noticable – Matt 14 secs ago edit  [delete this comment]

Comment: just switch out '/notice' with '/msg'